# Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.11.7.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#, html-agility-pack

I have F# console project which uses HtmlAgilityPack. It worked and I upgraded version 1.11.7.0. Now it got the following error?

> System.IO.FileLoadException
>
> HResult=0x80131040
>
> Message=Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.11.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: That looks like a binding redirect issue, so first check those, and if nothing can be found wrong with them, I guess it's time for fuslogvw.exe (or https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion).